# Exception : Cannot render a null template in Spring tiles

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have created one simple DAO interface and DAOImpl class for implementation of DAO. Taking data from the jsp and storing it to database. On successful completion I am rendering to a tiles to xml. I am getting below exception while returning view for tiles. Is there any problem in defining tiles as mentioned in this post ? The data is getting stored in the database but on the frontend I am getting the below exception and also on console.

```
 Aug 11, 2015 4:01:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [User] in context with path [/SpringUser] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.InvalidTemplateException: Cannot render a null template] with root cause
org.apache.tiles.impl.InvalidTemplateException: Cannot render a null template
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:51)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The tiles file for the same is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd"> 

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="user.reg" template="/jsp/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Sample App"/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value=""/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>           
        <put-attribute name="footer" value=""/>  
    </definition>
    <definition name="user.registration" extends="user.reg">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsp/success.jsp" />
    </definition>   
    <definition name="user.registrationUserSuccess" >
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsp/login.jsp" />
    </definition>   
    <definition name="user.home" >
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsp/login.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="user.profile">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsp/profile.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="user.error">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsp/error.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

The controller class for the same is as below -

```
package com.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.dao.UserDAO;
import com.entity.UserDetails;


@Controller
public class UserController {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class);
    String errForward = "user.error", forward = null;

   @Autowired
   UserDAO userDAO;

   UserDetails ud = new UserDetails();

   @RequestMapping("/registerUser")
   public String registerUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
       logger.info("### Inside registeration controller  ####");
       System.out.println("registerUser");
           int isSave=0;

           Date creation_time=null,lastModTime=null;
           SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz"); 
              Date date=new Date();
              String input = ft.format(date); 
              try { 
                  creation_time = ft.parse(input); 
                  lastModTime = ft.parse(input);
              } catch (ParseException e) { 
                  logger.error("/* Unable to parse date ****["+ ft+"]*****/");
              }

               String fName=request.getParameter("fName");
               fName=(fName.equals(""))?"":fName.trim();
               String lName=request.getParameter("lName");
               lName=(lName.equals(""))?"":lName.trim();
               int age=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
               age=(age==0)?0:age;
               String email=request.getParameter("email");
               email=(email.equals(""))?"":email.trim();
               String pswd=request.getParameter("pswd");
               pswd=(pswd.equals(""))?"":pswd.trim();

               ud.setFirstName(fName);
               ud.setLastName(lName);
               ud.setAge(age);
               ud.setPassword(pswd);
               ud.setEmail(email);
               ud.setCreationTime(creation_time);
               ud.setLastModTime(lastModTime);

           try{
               isSave=userDAO.saveUserDetails(ud);
               if (isSave==0){ 
                   forward="user.registrationUserSuccess";
                   logger.info("/******** Successfully saved the data :::["+isSave+"]::: *****/");
               }
           }catch(Exception e){
               logger.error("##### Error while saving use details #####"+e);
               return (forward);
           }
        return (forward);
   }

}
```

Contents of servlet file are as -

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- <bean id="sessionFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    </bean>  -->
   <mvc:annotation-driven/> 
   <context:annotation-config/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"></context:component-scan>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.dao"></context:component-scan>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.entity"></context:component-scan>

   <!-- title defining -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- defining title file location -->
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <import resource="db-config.xml" /> 

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean> 
</beans>
```

Comment: I'm wondering in this statement 'if (isSave==0){'. it seems like you check it it's false. In this case your forward name will be null.

Comment: No @Stan,  it's coming true. I have added some logs further - `###### The value of isSave is [0]%%%%%%%
::: Forward value :::[user.registrationUserSuccess]#####`

Comment: Thanks @Stan, for your answer. I have got the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the project from top to bottom. I did not find anything until I changed my directory structure. The jsp page path was inside WEB-INF folder, instead it should be outside WEB_INF and inside WEB CONTENT folder. After correcting the structure I got the required result.